# Laravel Count from database

Tags: laravel, count

I want to count the amount of workers a company has.
So it shows like: `McDonalds - 200 Employees`  (example)

**Model:**

```
 public function getTotalWorkers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\User')->whereCompanyId($this->company_id)->count();

    }
```

**View:**

```
@foreach($companies as $company)
<tr>
    <td>{!! link_to_route('company.edit', $company->name, [$company->id] )!!}</td>
    <td>{{ $getTotalWorkers }}</td>
    <td>{{ ' /' }}</td>
    <td>{{ $company->parent_id }}</td>
    <td>{{ ' /' }}</td>
    <td>{{ $company->active }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

**Controller:**

```
public function index()
{
    $getTotalWorkers = $this->company->getTotalWorkers();
    $companies = Company::get();

    return view('company.index', ['companies' => $companies, 'getTotalWorkers' => $getTotalWorkers]);
```

But this gives me an error: `Call to a member function getTotalWorkers() on a non-object`

How can I fix this or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you are calling `getTotalWorkers()` on `$post`, not `$company` on the fourth line of the view snippet you have posted.

Answer (score 0):

How you are doing it currently fundamentally will not work for what you want it to do.

You are currently calling ->getTotalWorkers() on your Controller class since you are using:

```
  $getTotalWorkers = $this->company->getTotalWorkers();
```

This wont work as the controller does not have this method (Your use of $this-> tells PHP to call it on the current class, it will work inside your model class but not on your controller. You have to call it on something, ie a company).

To get it to work how you are wanting it, remove that line from your controller, remove the `"getTotalWorkers" => $getTotalWorkers,` too.

In your view you can change:
      `<td>{{ $getTotalWorkers }}</td>`

To:

```
 <td>{{ $company->getTotalWorkers() }}</td>
```

Which will get it to count the number of workers for each company. Note this will run a new query for each different company you list.

Comment: With your changes it gives me the `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::getTotalWorkers()`